# set variable of flow from class apex through button in visualforce

Tags: visual-workflow

is it possible set a value of variable of flow thanks apex class using a button in the visualforce? 
I try to explain myself better,
I have a flow and a custom button in a visualforce, i would like that after click of button the field of flow is populated with a value that I defined in apex class.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set variables of flow from its' url.

There are various types of Flow variables. Use **Input and Output** variable in your case. You can use such variable in url and pass its' value to the flow from apex. Your method can be something like this.

```
public Pagereference openMyFlow() {

    String myVariableValue = 'some value';
    String flowUrl = '/flow/My_test_Flow?myIOvariable=' + myVariableValue;
    Pagereference pr = new Pagereference(flowUrl);

    return pr;
}
```